# Regex JS - How to replace whitespaces by "_" into expression into braces

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace whitespaces contained into an expression itself contained into brackets, w ?

```
var str = "This is my text {an other text} and blabla {again again}...";
```

REGEX JS CODE TO GET

```
"This is my text {an_other_text} and blabla {again_again}..."
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you mean "how to replace whitespace between brackets?" Can you have nested brackets? `[something [else here] you know]`?

Comment: Never nested braces (not brackets)

Comment: The other question still has your answer; just swap out `[` and `]` for `{` and `}` ...